# How to determine if a point lies inside a Concave Hull (Alpha Shape)?

Tags: python, graphics, polygon

I have a set of coordinates in a 2D plane from which I wish to construct a Concave Hull (Alpha Shape). After this, I need to determine if a certain point lies inside or outside the formed hull.

Although I can achieve this for Convex Hulls using the attached code, I haven't found a way to do the same for Concave Hulls.

```py
# Detection in Convex Hulls
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

hull = Delaunay(points)
return hull.find_simplex(test_point) >= 0
```

How can I achieve the same for Concave Hulls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **Alpha Shape package**. Here is an example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from descartes import PolygonPatch
import alphashape
import random
from shapely.geometry import Point

points = [(0., 0.), (0., 1.), (1., 1.), (1., 0.),
          (0.5, 0.25), (0.5, 0.75), (0.25, 0.5), (0.75, 0.5)]

alpha_shape = alphashape.alphashape(points, 2.0) # Create the alpha shape

# Plotting the alpha shape over the input data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(*zip(*points), c='green')
ax.add_patch(PolygonPatch(alpha_shape, alpha=0.2))

N = 10 # number of random points
for i in range(N):
    x = round(random.uniform(0, 1), 2)
    y = round(random.uniform(0, 1), 2)
    point = Point(x,y) # analysis point
    if alpha_shape.contains(point) == True:
        plt.scatter(x,y,c='blue')
    else:
        plt.scatter(x,y,c='red')
```

[image]

Legend:

1. In red, points outside the concave polygon
2. In green, the vertex points
3. In blue, the points inside the concave polygon

Answer (score 1):

Shapely contains point.within(polygon) and polygon.contains(point) methods.

Comment: The only way I know to create a poly in shapely is ```poly = MultiPoint(coords).convex_hull```.  This creates a convex hull, not a concave hull.

Comment: There is no concave hull function/method in shapely. There is a discusson and some code about it here: https://gist.github.com/dwyerk/10561690.